# Very challenging SQL interview (can't use stored procedure)

Tags: sql

You have a SQL table `table` with two columns: `name` and `pen`. Both columns are text strings.

```
name  | pen
---------------    
mike  | red
mike  | red
mike  | blue
mike  | green
steve | red
steve | yellow
anton | red
anton | blue
anton | green
anton | black
alex  | black
alex  | green
alex  | yellow
alex  | red
```

Person's name is given as the input argument.

Please write a SQL statement (not a stored procedure) which returns names of persons having unique set of pens which is equivalent or wider/bigger than the set of pens of given person.

Examples:

- input: mike
- output: anton

Mike has (red, blue, green).
Anton has more gadgets (red, blue, green) + black.

- input: steve
- output: alex

Steve has (red, yellow).
Alex has (red, yellow) + green+ black.
Mike, Anton aren't printed - they do not have yellow.

- input: alex
- output:

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Is that **your** homework?. What did you do so far?.

Comment: [This is relational division.](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Answer (score 13):

Here's one way ([Online Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/118441/)), assuming input name "steve".

This can be rephrased as "Looking for all users for which there does not exist a pen owned by steve that they do not own"

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM   table t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   table t2
                   WHERE  name = 'steve'
                          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                          FROM   table t3
                                          WHERE  t2.pen = t3.pen
                                                 AND t1.name = t3.name))  
AND t1.name <> 'steve' /*Exclude input name from results*/
```

[See this article for other techniques](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: Thanks, Martin, just add one more condition:SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM   table t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   table t2
                   WHERE  name = 'Alex'
                          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                          FROM   table t3
                                          WHERE  t2.pen = t3.pen
                                                 AND t1.name = t3.name))  and name <> 'Alex'

Answer (score 1):

```
  with test1 as
   (select a.name nm, count(distinct a.pen) ct
      from table a, table b
     where b.pen = a.pen
       and b.name = 'anton'
     group by a.name
     order by 2 desc),
  test2 as
   (select  nm name1
    from test1
    where ct = (select max(ct) from test1))
  select distinct c.name 
    from table c
   where c.name in (select name1
                      from test2
                      where name1 not in (case
                             when (select count(distinct name1) from test2) > 1 then
                              'anton'
                             else
                              ' '
                           end))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Table Format:

E_NAME  E_PEN
----------------
mike    green 
mike    blue  
mike    red   
mike    red   
steve   red   
steve   yellow
anton   red   
anton   blue  
anton   green 
anton   black 
alex    black 
alex    green 
alex    yellow
alex    red   


Query: 



SELECT A.E_NAME, A.E_PEN
  FROM V_NAME A, V_NAME B
 WHERE TRIM(UPPER(A.E_NAME)) = TRIM(UPPER(B.E_NAME))
   AND TRIM(UPPER(A.E_NAME)) != 'MIKE'
   AND TRIM(UPPER(A.E_PEN)) = TRIM(UPPER(B.E_PEN(+)))

Procedure to take Input from user: 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE E_TEST(I_NAME VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE E_TABLE AS
                   SELECT A.E_NAME,A.E_PEN FROM V_NAME A,V_NAME B
                   WHERE TRIM(UPPER(A.E_NAME)) = TRIM(UPPER(B.E_NAME))
                   AND TRIM(UPPER(A.E_NAME)) != ''' ||
                    I_NAME || '''
                   AND TRIM(UPPER(A.E_PEN))= TRIM(UPPER(B.E_PEN(+)))';
END;

Name: Nikhil Shinde
E-Mail: nikhilshinde3jun@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (name nvarchar(20), pen nvarchar(20))
insert into @t (name,pen)
values('mike','red'),
('mike','red'),
('mike','blue'),
('mike','green'),
('steve','red'),
('steve','yellow'),
('anton','red'),
('anton','blue'),
('anton','green'),
('anton','black'),
('alex','black'),
('alex','green'),
('alex','yellow'),
('alex','red')

declare @input nvarchar(20) = 'mike';

with cte_input (name, pen)
as
(
    select distinct name, pen
    from @t 
    where name = @input
)
, cte_colors (name, matches)
as
(
    select name, matches = count(distinct pen)
    from @t 
    where name != @input      
      and pen in (select pen from cte_input)
      group by name
    having count(distinct pen) = (select count(1) from cte_input)
)
select t.name 
from   @t t
join   cte_colors m on m.name = t.name
group by t.name, m.matches
having count(distinct t.pen) > m.matches
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use LEAD analytical function to achieve this solution.

The query would be

```
select next_name from
(select name, count(pen) CNT, LEAD(name,1) over (order by count(pen)) next_name 
from table
group by name order by CNT
)
where name=input_value;
```

the sub query will give the results as below

## name  | CNT | next_name

mike  | 3   | Steve

steve | 2   | anton

anton | 4   | alex

alex  | 4   | (null)

Then the out query filter the row required and gives the `next_name` which is what we are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

create table practise
(
 name varchar (10),pens varchar (10)

)
 insert practise (name,pens)
 select 'mike','red' union
 select 'mike','red' union
 select 'mike','blue' union
 select 'mike','green' union
 select 'steve','red' union
 select 'steve','yellow' union
 select 'anton','blue' union
 select 'anton','green' union
 select 'anton','black' union
 select 'anton','red' union
 select 'alex','black' union
 select 'alex','green' union
 select 'alex','yellow' union
 select 'alex','red'

select * into #t from practise

```
 update #t
 set Colourcode = 1 where pens = 'black'
 go 
 update #t
 set Colourcode = 2 where pens = 'blue' 
 go 
 update #t
 set Colourcode = 3 where pens = 'green' 
 go 
 update #t
 set Colourcode = 4 where pens = 'red'
 go 
 update #t 
 set Colourcode = 5 where pens = 'yellow'
```

select distinct colourcode  from #t

/* IMP Code */
update #t
set Number = 
(
select count(*) from #t
where name = 'steve' and colourcode = 1
)
where name = 'steve' and colourcode = 1

/* once the above update statement is exected change colourcode = 2 and again run the statement
                                              change colourcode = 3 and again run the statement
                                              change colourcode = 4 and again run the statement
                                              change colourcode = 5 and again run the statement*/

/* Follow the same process for name 'alex','anton' and 'mike' */

/* Below is the Solution*/

select name from #t
where number =
(
select distinct number from #t
where colourcode = 3 and  Number =1)

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @name nvarchar(20)
set @name = 'steve';
with cte_in
as
(
select distinct Pen from tblNamePen where Name = @name
)

select Name from 
(
select t1.name, count(distinct t1.Pen) ct from tblNamePen t1
join cte_in inp on t1.Name <> @name
where t1.pen = inp.Pen
group by t1.Name
) a
where a.ct >= (select count(Pen) from cte_in)
```